# Google ADX Seller Rest API scopes

Tags: oauth, google-api, adsense, double-click

I'm having some issues with the above api that I can't seem to solve and would appreciate any help: I'm trying to build an oauth url with the scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adexchange.seller+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adexchange.seller.readonly and i'm not prompted for those permissions when redirecting to the oauth urls.

I've taken the developer console URIs and only changed the client_id and redirect_uri and it still doesn't work, so I believe the problem is with my google developer console application?

e.g. the google developer console URI which prompts me to authorise for "View and manage your Ad Exchange data" and "View your Ad Exchange data" is:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adexchange.seller+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adexchange.seller.readonly&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground&approval_prompt=force&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com

Now if I only change the client_id and redirect_uri to use my application i only get prompted to "Have offline access" which in turn does not allow me to access any data as it says that this user does not have any adx account.

Both cases I'm authenticating with the same user (I also tried with other adx users), using a "client id for web application" credential.

Thanks
Amnon

Answer (score 1):

If anyone ever has this problem: the issue was caused because I once tried to authenticate with a google credential for installed application and for some reason until I revoked the access for the application from google.com/settings it wouldn't prompt me for the correct scopes. after revoking everything started working as expected.

Amnon